# Next Scene not loading when requested to

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created a game where when the user breaks all the blocks he is taken to the next scene but this is not happening despite adding all of the scenes I have in the build settings. I have no errors whatsoever and the scene is written correctly. Can someone help me resolve this, please?

This is the build settings
 [image]

Bricks script : (where the scene is called)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Bricks : MonoBehaviour {

public LevelManager myLevelManager;
public static int brickCount = 0;
public int maxNumberOfHits = 0;
int timesHit;
public AudioClip BlockBreaking;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    timesHit = 0;

    if(this.gameObject.tag == "BrickHit")
    {
        brickCount++;

    }

    if(this.gameObject.tag == "BrickHitTwice")
    {
        brickCount++;
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D()
{
    timesHit++;

    if (timesHit == maxNumberOfHits)
    {
        brickCount--;
        Destroy(this.gameObject); 
    }

    if(brickCount == 0)
    {
        myLevelManager.LoadLevel("Level1.2"); //THIS SCENE IS NOT LOADING
    }

    if(this.gameObject.tag == "BrickHit") //If the gameObject (Block One Point) with the tag "BrickHit" is hit
    {
        Scores.scoreValue += 1;//The user will be rewarded 1 point
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(BlockBreaking, transform.position);
    }

    if(this.gameObject.tag == "BrickHitTwice") //If the gameObject (Block Two Points) with the tag "BrickHitTwice" is hit
    {
        Scores.scoreValue += 2; //The user will be rewarded 2 points
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(BlockBreaking, transform.position);
    }   
}
```

LevelManager Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour {
    public void LoadLevel(string name)
    {
       print("Level loading requested for" + name);
       SceneManager.LoadScene(name);
    }
```

Comment: Is it printing the "Level loading" text to the console?

Comment: @jmalenfant No, it is not :/. But I think it is unity having a bug because I have tried this multiple times and it sometimes works and it sometimes doesn't

Comment: Is there anyway to make it work everytime ?

Comment: I suspect there are instances where brickCount should be zero, but isn't for some reason. Have you tried adding something like: `print("Bricks: " + brickCount);` before `if (brickCount == 0)`? Just to make sure the count actually hits zero (or goes below zero).

Comment: Could you please tell us the desired gameplay behaviour? And also, have you made sure that maxNumberOfHits is assigned in the inspector?

Comment: @FredrikSchön Yes the number of hits is assigned in the inspector.
@jmalenfant i added `print("Bricks: " + brickCount);` it is just counting how many briks i have broken

Comment: @Mizzi and does it hit zero when you would expect it to?

Comment: @jmalenfant it starts printing just fine then when it gets to 12 it starts printing -1, -2 etc. Mind you I have 40 blocks.

Comment: @Mizzi alright, let's change the if statement to `if (brickCount <= 0)` instead of `if (brickCount == 0)` and see if that works for you

Comment: @jmalenfant This is working in a way that when the brickcount hits -1 it takes me to the scene I want it even if all the bricks aren't all destroyed

Comment: I think I know what's going on now. One last question before I post an answer. Is this script attached to each brick?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to create a prefab so I had to attach it to every single brick

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your bug may lie in the fact that you're `Destroy()`ing the gameObject before it can load the next scene; you get a race condition on what will finish first; LoadScene or Destroy() - which would explain why it *sometimes work*. You should never assume it is a bug in the framework before understanding your problem.

**Try putting the Destroy() after the LoadScene() or with a delay to understand if this is your issue.**

---

Also, your LevelManager can be made static and doesn't need to inherit from MonoBehaviour since it doesn't use gameObject functionality.

```
public static class LevelManager {
    public static void LoadLevel(string name)
    {
       print("Level loading requested for" + name);
       SceneManager.LoadScene(name);
    }
}
```

Used by doing `LevelManager.LoadLevel("MyLevel");`, but then you may question what is more effective, doing LevelManager.LoadLevel or SceneManager.LoadLevel, as they will do the exact same thing.

Comment: I did `Destroy(this.gameObject);` after the `myLevelManager.LoadLevel("Level1.2");` so it became like this : `if(brickCount == 0)
    {
        myLevelManager.LoadLevel("Level1.2"); //THIS SCENE IS NOT LOADING
         Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }`
This is not working since now the bricks aren't being destroyed

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem. The object won't get destroyed until after `Update()` and physics events like `OnCollisionEnter2D()` run before `Update()` as per [Unity Order of Execution](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)

Comment: Okay I saw your comment @jmalenfant I am trying it right now

Comment: @jmalenfant https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html

Comment: More specifically, `When using SceneManager.LoadScene, the loading does not happen immediately, it completes in the next frame. This semi-asynchronous behavior can cause frame stuttering and can be confusing because load does not complete immediately.`. I've seen this issue before where people destroy the object responsible for changing scene the scene and get some kind of race condition. Ultimately your suggested answer is the best solution.

Comment: @Mizzi @"This is not working since now the bricks aren't being destroyed", destroying bricks doesn't matter, only brickCount since your condition for loading the next scene is `if(brickCount == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

The main issue that you're having is not having a single source to check `brickCount` instead each individual brick is maintaining its own count. I would recommend moving the brick counting logic into a separate class. It would seem like `LevelManager` would a good place for it. So in LevelManager add:

```
private int brickCount = 0;
public void AddBrick()
{
    brickCount++;
}
public void RemoveBrick()
{
    brickCount--;
    // Check if all bricks are destroyed
    if (brickCount == 0)
    {
        LoadLevel("Level1.2");
    }
}
```

And then in your brick script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Bricks : MonoBehaviour {
    public LevelManager myLevelManager;        
    public int maxNumberOfHits = 0;
    int timesHit;
    public AudioClip BlockBreaking;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        timesHit = 0;
        myLevelManager.AddBrick();
        // I'm not sure why you were checking the tag here, since the result was the same  
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D()
    {
        timesHit++;

        if (timesHit == maxNumberOfHits)
        {
            myLevelManager.RemoveBrick();
            Destroy(this.gameObject); 
        }
        /* This looks like the player is getting score whether the brick is destroyed or not. Also, it would appear the player won't get scored on the final brick */
        if(this.gameObject.tag == "BrickHit") //If the gameObject (Block One Point) with the tag "BrickHit" is hit
        {
            Scores.scoreValue += 1;//The user will be rewarded 1 point
            AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(BlockBreaking, transform.position);
        }

        if(this.gameObject.tag == "BrickHitTwice") //If the gameObject (Block Two Points) with the tag "BrickHitTwice" is hit
        {
            Scores.scoreValue += 2; //The user will be rewarded 2 points
            AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(BlockBreaking, transform.position);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will be trying this soon since I am working on a database at the moment. I will let you know if it worked for me.

Comment: It wont let me attach the levelmanagerobject to the mylevelmanager variable that is on the bricks script

Comment: The brickcount is static, not "individual" - I don't see how your suggested edit would make any difference.

Comment: @jmalenfant Okay it is letting me adding it now but however it's still not taking me to the next scene

Comment: @FredrikSchön Do you have any ideas on how this could be solved?

Comment: @jmalenfant 

Thank you both for your help but I have figured out what was the problem :)